# Java Generic TypeOf Return T

Tags: java

```
public Object Convert(Class<T> Type) {
    if (Type == Integer.class) {
        return Integer.parseInt(DataInfo);
    } else if (Type == String.class ) {
        return DataInfo;
    } else if (Type == Double.class) {
        return Double.parseDouble(DataInfo);
    }
    return null;

}
```

Is there any other way that I can do this?

I just want to do something like:  `int X = Foo.Convert<int>();`

Where it takes a string and converts it to `<Type>` <----- That. I tried:

```
public T Convert()
{
}
```

But I searched everywhere and Java doesn't have a typeof function :S Basically trying to convert a string from the user to a data type.

EDIT.. I'm asking because in C++ I usually do:

```
template <typename T>
inline T ToNumber(const std::string &Text){std::istringstream SS(Text); T Result; return (SS >> Result ? Result : 0);}
```

I wanted to know if in Java I can do that.. I was using it like:

```
package test;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Data<T> {
    private String DataInfo;

    public String ReadBuffer() throws IOException {
        BufferedReader Buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        return (DataInfo = Buffer.readLine());
    }

    public String ReadConsole() {
        Console Con = System.console();
        return (DataInfo = Con.readLine());
    }

    public String Read() {
        Scanner Reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        return (DataInfo = Reader.next());
    }

    public Object Convert(Class<T> Type) {
        if (Type == Integer.class) {
            return Integer.parseInt(DataInfo);
        } else if (Type == String.class ) {
            return DataInfo;
        } else if (Type == Double.class) {
            return Double.parseDouble(DataInfo);
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950800/java-generic-string-to-t-parser

Comment: What does the user of your function gain by it being generic?  In other words, why wouldn't a user just use `int x = Integer.parseInt("2");` when he needs an `int`, `Foo f = Foo.valueOf("fooData{2,3}")` when he needs a `Foo`, etc?  Seems to me that the caller will need to know the concrete type, and the logic will do something different based on the concrete type, so there's not much gain in it being generic.

Comment: Well I'm the only user of this class and I wanted to know if I can do it like that.

Currently, I created a console class and I wanted to convert a string to any type..

In C++ i usually do:
`
template <typename T>
inline T ToNumber(const std::string &Text){std::istringstream SS(Text); T Result; return (SS >> Result ? Result : 0);}`

I wanted to do it in Java too ={

Comment: I edited the question so you can see what I was doing in C++ and what I'm attempting in Java but someone below said it's not possible. I guess I'll give up on it then..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to type erasure, that is completely impossible.

The best you can do it have the caller pass a `Class<T>`.

Comment: Ahh ok Thank you. Kind of disappointed as I'm just learning java and this was one of the first things that come to mind. Casting. But I guess it's fine to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can look at com.google.inject.TypeLiteral since it can get you by the erasure.  It will keep the raw (non-generic) type.