# Generic method returns the correct Object while assigning to variable but not when used with a method

Tags: java, generics

I am using some code with generics in which I am unsure why there is a compile error being thrown.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.print("s");
    setInteger(prepareNumber("1")); // Error here! solved by casting: setInteger((Integer)prepareNumber("1"))
    Integer c = prepareInteger("1");
    System.out.print(c);

  }

  public static Integer prepareInteger(Object number) {
    return prepareNumber(number).intValue();
  }

  private static <T extends Number> T prepareNumber(Object number) {

    T returnValue = null;

    // handle a blank number
    if (number == null || !NumberUtils.isNumber(number.toString())) {
      returnValue = null;
    } else {
      if (number.toString().contains(".")) {
        returnValue = (T) Double.valueOf(number.toString());
      } else {
        returnValue = (T) Integer.valueOf(number.toString());
      }
    }

    return returnValue;
  }

  private static void setInteger(Integer a){    
  }
```

Fixing this is easy by just doing a casting, but that is undesired, as the generics should detect the method needs an Integer and should provide the return value as such and not as the super type.

PS: Do not mind the parsing code, is just testing stuff.

Thanks!

Comment: What does the message of the error say? Isn't it self-explanatory?

Comment: prepareNumber returns a Number, which may not be an Integer. In fact, your 'fix' will raise a ClassCastException if `number.toString().contains(".")`. The real question is, why do you pass setInteger something that may not be an Integer?

Comment: Actually, <T> T method() essentially says: "this method returns something that can be compile-time converted to every reference type", thus the only value that the method may return is null. In fact, your code raises generic-related warnings (javac -Xlint:unchecked); and Java does not guarantee type safety in presence of generic-related warnings. `prepareNumber` has actually no reason to be generic: a plain `Number prepareNumber(Object number)` will be fine.

Comment: @JB : The method raises the following error:
The method setInteger(Integer) in the type Test is not applicable for the arguments (Number)

Comment: @Ignis : The reason for wanting it to be generic is basically because I am getting Integers or Doubles as Strings and I need to parse them and put them in the setters for the Object, be it either attribute.

Comment: @will284, you want compile-time type safety that depends on the program flow. This is not something in the power of Java, at the moment.

Comment: Yes, seems In order to prevent the generic information to be lost I will have to use the signature: private <T> T prepareNumber(Object number, Class<T> type), as recommended here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950800/java-generic-string-to-t-parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is unable to infer what type `prepareNumber("1")` is supposed to return in this case. You can get it to infer correctly by placing the result in a temporary variable:

```
Integer value = prepareNumber("1");        
setInteger(value);
```

Or you if `parseNumber` is a static method in class `YourClass` you can explicitly tell the compiler what type you expect like so:

```
setInteger(YourClass.<Integer>prepareNumber("1"));
```

---

Or if you are okay with changing the method signature to help the compiler:

```
setInteger(prepareNumber("1", Integer.class));

private static <T extends Number> T prepareNumber(Object number, Class<T> classType) {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know the compiler cannot know for sure what type the returning object will have, but in the method I am controlling that it will be Integer or Double depending on conditions, so I was expecting it to resolve using the method signature :(

Comment: Nice information, I did not know you could define what you are expecting in this way. Still I have the same problem and is that I need if to be able to know what to expect for the setter method, but it looks like I will have to make a couple of intermediate methods and use them.

Comment: Well if you want to spare yourself an intermediate method, you can add a class token parameter .. see my edit.

Comment: Also, another way to spare another method and make use of generics in this case is to change the signature of the method: private <T> T prepareNumber(Object number, Class<T> type)

Answer (score 0):

prepareNumber method return the type of Number which is the super class of Integer but your setInteger is accepting Integer and there is no implicitly casting in this scenario.