# Manipulating Generics through auto/unboxing

Tags: java, generics, autoboxing, unboxing

```
public class Generics {

    public static <T> T increaseBalance (T amount){
        //say I want to increase the amount here, put it into finalBalance and return
        return finalBalance;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(increaseBalance (new Integer(10)));
        System.out.println(increaseBalance (new Double(20)));
    }

}
```

Hi. I am just into Generics and auto/unboxing. In this simple code segment, I am trying to send two different objects to `increaseBalance(T amount)` method and would like to increase the amount by 10 and return the final balance. How can this be achieved? It would make my understanding of generics and auto/unboxing clearer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: After a quick read I'm not sure, but does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16030157/java-generics-and-numeric-types) question of mine cover what you are asking?

Comment: It's hard to find a "nice" solution for this. What if the method tried to add `0.001` to an `Integer`?

Comment: you don't need generics here, you need overloading -- numeric types have no common methods for arithmetics you could use in `increaseBalance`

Comment: "numeric types have no common methods for arithmetics you could use in increaseBalance" - aha! Got the point.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to apply the `+` operator to a Generic type `T`.

You have two options:

- Overloading

or

- Checking the type and casting to a specific boxed type

If you pick to overloading, you can implement two methods, both for each of the possible parameter types.

```
public static Integer increaseBalance (Integer amount){
    return amount + 10;
}

public static Double increaseBalance (Double amount){
    return amount + 10;
}
```

If you want to stick to the generic method, you will have to check the parameter type and then do a cast.

```
public static <T extends Number> Number increaseBalance (T amount){
    Number result = null;
    if (amount instanceof Integer) {
        result = new Integer((Integer) amount + 10);
    } else if (amount instanceof Double) {
        result = new Double((Double) amount + 10);
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I was about to submit the same solution .. +1

Comment: you can use amount.doubleValue() no matter what type it is

Comment: FYI you could use `amount.intValue()` and `amount.doubleValue()` instead of casting.

Comment: @KalpeshSoni Actually we're saying subtly different things.  I don't think you should use `doubleValue()` for both.

Comment: Nice guys. Learned an important thing here.

Comment: I was wondering, what can be a nice way to stop manipulating a String that could be accidentally sent to the increaseBalance method? else if (amount instanceof String) {//do nothing?}